# Show matrix is nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $( {X}^\intercal{X},{V})$ has rank $p$, where ${X}^\intercal{X}$ is $p\times p$ of rank $q$, $0<q<p$, and ${V}$ is $p\times (p-q)$ of rank $p-q$. Show that ${W}$ is nonsingular, where $${W} = \begin{pmatrix} {X}^\intercal{X} & {V} \\ {V}^\intercal & {0}\end{pmatrix}$$

Hint: Show that if $Wu=0$ then $u=0$.

Could you guys point me in the right direction. Specficially, I am not seeing how the hint is connected with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is that a square matrix $W$ is nonsingular iff $W u = 0$ implies $u=0$.

Write $u = \pmatrix{v\cr w\cr}$, so $X^T X v + V w = 0$ and $V^T v = 0$.

Next step: expand $v^T (X^T X v + V w) = 0$.

What does this tell you about $X v$?

What does the rank of $\pmatrix{X^T X\cr V^T\cr}$ tell you about $v$?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the hint. I was able to get that $Xv=0$ (is that what you were hinting at?) I'm still working on your 2nd hint.

Answer (score 0):

Take and arbitary vector $u=(x,y)$ where $x$ is $p$ vector and $y$ is $p-q$ vector.  Then

$$
Wu=a+b
$$
where
$$
a=\Big(\matrix{X^TX \\
V^T}\Big)x 
$$
$$
b=\Big(\matrix{V\\0}\Big)y
$$
 $a=0$  iff $x=0$ ($(X^TX,V)$ has $p$ rank).

$b=0$ iff $y=0$ ($V$ has $p-q$ rank.) 
Assume that $a=-b$ but then $X^TX x=-V y$ and $V^Tx=0$ .Then $x^TX^TXx=0$. Therefore $X^TXx=Vy=0$ then $y=0$ then $a=b=u=0$. This completes the proof.

Comment: ???   If $a = \pmatrix{X^T X\cr V^T} x$ which is $(2p-q) \times 1$ and $b = V y$ which is $p \times 1$, then
$Wu = a + \pmatrix{b\cr 0}$, not $\pmatrix{a\cr b\cr}$ which has the wrong shape.

Comment: Yes, I made mistake, sorry.  I will fix or delete the answer